# Sort custom taxonomy terms order by both count and name

Tags: custom-taxonomy, sort

I am working on a custom taxonomy sorting to make popular terms. The requirement is to sort by popular posts by post count and also I need to sort terms by name to get it alphabetical order.

Here is my code

```
$args = array(
'hide_empty' => 0 ,
'orderby' => 'count',
'orderby' => 'name',
'parent'=> $cat_main->term_id
);

$terms = get_terms('question_type',$args);
```

Another condition is that `orderby` `count` has to be `DESC` and `orderby` name has to be 'ASC'

Any suggestions?

Comment: Please provide an example of the expected output. Your question is a bit confusing

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This won't be possible via the function itself or to be exact by just providing parameters/arguments. You have to do this via hooks to alter the default behavior, I think. You should take a closer look at at least two, they are: [`get_terms_orderby`](https://github.com/WordPress/WordPress/blob/master/wp-includes/taxonomy.php#L1379) and/or [`terms_clauses`](https://github.com/WordPress/WordPress/blob/master/wp-includes/taxonomy.php#L1548).